# Wrapping a C function with FFI for Ruby

Tags: c++, c, ruby, ffi

I admittedly struggle with C and C++, but I'm trying to wrap a C++ function (extern to 'C') in FFI but don't quite understand the syntax.

The form of the externed C code is:

```
Client *create_client(Address *address, const char * const foo){
//make stuff  
}
```

My question, specifically, is how to wrap that in Ruby using FFI? I *think* the constructor takes two pointers, so it would be of form:

```
attach_function :create_client, [:pointer, :pointer], :pointer
```

But, on the other hand, the const char * const foo confuses me - should it be treated as a string like so:

```
attach_function :create_client, [:pointer, :string], :pointer
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
attach_function :create_client, [:pointer, :string], :pointer
```

The `const char *` means its a c string the `const` part after only matters to the function your calling. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/103108/) for more details. The function you wrapped looks correct to me but im assuming you need more than this function which will be more complex.

The FFI wiki has some good info [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki).

Comment: 1) So, the "important" part for wrapping is everything to the left of the asterisk?
2) If there are double asterisks, is that then considered a pointer?

Comment: For wrapping the important part is to the left. And for your second question its still a pointer (its a pointer that points to a pointer).

Comment: Once I get everything wrapped I'll know for certain if this is right - thanks for your help! Now for me to sort out when  * is a pointer or indicative of something else (like a string)!